# URL query string "get=family&code={segment_code}&lang=en" must not have replace block

Tags: android, url, retrofit

I'm getting an error as IllegalException on path
following is my code:

```
@GET("/gpc?get=family&code={segment_code}&lang=en")
void getFamily(@Header("Authorization") String authKey
,@Header("Accept-version") String version
,@Path("segment_code") String segment_code
,Callback<Family> callback);
```

Comment: post whole code and logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have "query" replacement blocks in the URL that you pass to Retrofit. Change your method like this:

```
@GET("/gpc")    
void getFamily(@Header("Authorization") String authKey, @Header("Accept-version") String version, @Query("segment_code") String segment_code, @Query("family") String family, @Query("lang") String en, Callback<Family> callback);
```

Comment: Let me try this, i want this type of format, the code value is dynamic will your code work? in this case:  /gpc?get=family&code=4545454&lang=en, 454545 get replace with my value

Comment: I am getting this error: URL "/gpc" does not contain "{segment_code}". (parameter #3)